# getFromLocation in API Level 19

Tags: java, android, location, geocoder

i have a function getCountry which return country name:

```
public String getCoutry(double longitude, double latitude){
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    String country = "";
    List<Address> address = null;
    try{
        address = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (address != null || address.size() != 0)
        {
            Address object = address.get(0);
            country = object.getCountryName();
        }else{
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return country;
}
```

With android version 21 and greater work perfect but in 19 sdk application has stopped, address.size equals 0, Why?

Longitude: 14.8260
latitude: 50.8706

Logcat:

```
11-20 13:04:22.885: D/EGL_emulation(2487): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb8522580: ver 2 0
11-20 13:04:22.905: D/AndroidRuntime(2487): Shutting down VM
11-20 13:04:22.905: W/dalvikvm(2487): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cf9b20)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487): Process: nusssoftware.tachonuss, PID: 2487
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at nusssoftware.tachonuss.GpsLocation.getCoutry(GpsLocation.java:95)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at nusssoftware.tachonuss.GpsLocation$1.onClick(GpsLocation.java:79)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-20 13:04:22.905: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: `sdk application has stopped` show logcat

Comment: add `if (address != null && address.size() > 0)`

Comment: "Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available."  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html